# How get a value from a puppet resource

Tags: puppet

I have a problem with my puppet script.

I would like to get a value set in my resource file. I declare a resource like that

```
define checkxml(
  $account = '',
  $pwd = template('abc/abc.erb'),
){
  if(empty($pwd)){
    fail('pwd empty') 
  }
}
```

I call it via :

```
checkxml{"$agtaccount":
  account => $agtaccount,
}
```

I want to get the value of $pwd. The $pwd will get is value by Template. If i try to show the value in my resource definition it's ok, I get the right value, so the Template works fine.

My problem is to get access this value after calling the ressource. I saw the getparam of [stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#getparam) but doesn't work for me.

```
getparam(Checkxml["$agtaccount"],"pwd")
```

If i try to get the account parameters instead of pwd it's ok. I think as i doesn't declare the pwd i can't get him back

How can i get him ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, this looks dangerous. First off I'd recommend to steer clear of that function and the concept it embodies. It faces you with evaluation order dependencies, which can always lead to inconsistent manifest behavior.

As for the retrieval of the value itself - that will likely not work if the default is used. That's because on a catalog building level, there is not yet a value that is being bound to the parameter, if that makes any sense.

The resolution of final parameter values is rather involved, so there are lots of things that can go wrong with a manifest that relies on such introspective functionality.

I recommend to retrieve the desired value in a more central location (that depends on your manifest structure) and use it both when declaring the Checkxml["$agtaccount"] resource as well as its other uses (for which you are currently trying to extract it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
The $agtaccount contain my username. My goal here is to get the password associated to this account. The password is saved in xml file.  
My Template, return the password for the account specified in the $account variable when I call the resource.So the password can't be retrieve before i called the Template, and I doesn't want to set manually the password.  
If i have to get this only one time, it will be fine (using a class, and access the variable after) but the major problem here is I have a lot of accounts, so a lot of passwords to get back.

Comment: You should consider storing that data in Hiera instead of the external XML source.

Comment: using xml instead of hiera would be better, because, in my case, this data is used by another programs, and scripts, and I need them available.
I continue to try with puppet, maybe i will find a way.
Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: You could generate the XML **from** Puppet and deploy it for use by other components. In the end, it's just important that you have a nonambiguous data source.